# Check if vector have no cube values of another element

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I have the following algorithm, can somebody help me solve this? I just need an explanation.

"A vector a[] with n integer elements is cube-repetition-free if no element is the cube of
another element, i.e., there are no indices i,j such that a[i] = a[j]3 . Propose an
O(n*log(n))-time algorithm in order to decide whether a vector is cube-repetition-free."

Comment: sort the vector, iterate through the vector calculating the cubes and checking whether elements after that element are the cube (maybe with a binary search)

Comment: so what's your question? You already have the algorithm `I have the following algorithm [...]`. So if  you already have it what do you need? The problem is clear: the vector (8,5,2) is an example of not cube-repetition-free because 2 to the cube is 8 `2^3=8`. The vector (7,5,3) is an example of cube-repetition-free because none of its elements is a cube of another element.

Comment: A simple possibility is to use a `std::set`. Put the elements in the set. Then, for each element`x`, check if `x*x*x` is in the set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer guys, I know now, how should I code this.

Comment: @Damien. Vector (1,2,3) will give that 1^ 3 is in the set (itself). It's not clear if this is allowed since it says `another element` but mathematically is doesn't force `i` to be different than `j`. In any case your solution will make any vector containing 0, 1 or -1  non cube-repetition-free

Comment: Why O(nlogn) when you can have O(n)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O(n) solution:

1. Add each element v[i] of the vector to a hash set.
2. For each element v[i] check whether v[i] * v[i] * v[i] is in the set.

O(n*logn) solution:

1. Sort the vector v.
2. Pointers start = 0 and end = 1.
3. While end < n do the following:

   1. if v[start] * v[start] * v[start] equals v[end] then the vector is not cube-repetition-free.
   2. if v[start] * v[start] * v[start] < v[end] then increment start.
   3. Otherwise increment end.